# Express and JSHtml produces TypeError

Tags: node.js, express, jshtml

I'm starting to learn Node.JS for web aplications using Express. Initially looking at Jade, I wanted something more... HTML-y. So, I looked at jshtml. I used this to generate a boilerplate app:

```
$ express --jshtml -c less
```

And this generated something that looks pretty normal to me. However, when I actually run it, I get this trying to view the index page:

```
TypeError: Property 'engine' of object #<View> is not a function
    at View.render (/home/earlz/projects/extest/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (/home/earlz/projects/extest/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:504:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/earlz/projects/extest/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:798:7)
    at exports.index (/home/earlz/projects/extest/routes/index.js:7:7)
    at callbacks (/home/earlz/projects/extest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/home/earlz/projects/extest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/home/earlz/projects/extest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/earlz/projects/extest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (/home/earlz/projects/extest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/home/earlz/projects/extest/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
GET / 500 20ms
```

Do I have to install something else? Or how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [jshtml engine](https://github.com/elmerbulthuis/jshtml-express) for express and use it while configuring your server.

```
npm install jshtml-express
```

configure your server like this;

```
var jshtml = require('jshtml-express');

app.engine('jshtml', jshtml); 
app.set('view engine', 'jshtml');
```

Hope this helps. :)